# Using applicationSettings complains about user-level appSettings -- can I avoid this?

Tags: java, c#, .net, app-config, j#

I have a pre-existing application that is using <appSettings> with several keys that are accessed using ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.  One component of this application happens to be java code built with J# that uses java.util.prefs.Preferences to load and save some user preferences.

Recently, we added some new configuration and opted to use the designer-generated <applicationSettings> for new settings.  But now the application fails on startup with this exception:

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException It is an error to
>   use a section registered as allowExeDefinition='MachineToApplication'
>   beyond the application, in the user's config.  (This is the default
>   behavior if not specified)
>   (C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\COMPANY\BIGLONGSTRING\user.config
>   line 3)    at
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean
>   ignoreLocal)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()    at
>   System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.OnConfigRemoved(Object
>   sender, InternalConfigEventArgs e)

The "user.config" file named contains the java user preferences keys inside of an <appSettings> section.

It seems that the applicationSettings parser is the one throwing the exception, as it only showed up after adding the new settings.  I understand that the appSettings section is defined as allowExeDefinition='MachineToApplication' so it is technically invalid for the user config file to exist.  However, the presence of this file does not impede me from using ConfigurationManager.AppSettings to obtain values from app.config file.  The user.config is **only** read via java prefs.

Is there any way I can configure my application so that the applicationSettings parser (which is type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089", inserted by the designer) will ignore the user.config appSettings section?  I don't understand why it is even *parsing* anything outside of section applicationSettings.

FWIW: we're targeting .Net Framework 3.5.